# Custom caching for ListView with filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listcollectionview

I have a `ListView` with a `GridView` in my C# WPF application. The `ItemsSource` is bound to a `ListCollectionView` created on the `ViewModel` from an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. I use the `ListCollectionView` for dynamic sorting, filtering and grouping, all of which can be adjusted or turned on/off from the `View`.

When I alter the filter or turn the grouping on/off, all of the visual list view items are recreated, which causes the UI to freeze for about a second. Since I have about 250 items displayed and there are about 10 columns (some of which have cell templates with a progressbar), this comes as no surprise.

Now, I know that the obvious answer is to enable virtualization. This however, brings some undesirable effects, such as scrolling becoming jerky or the scroll-bar changing its size as you scroll (this happens with grouping on, since the groups vary in height and so the virtualizing stack panel can not calculate the total height properly at first).

What I would like to do is to have the `ListView` keep a visual element for every item in the raw list (un-filtered and un-sorted, i.e. the `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`) and then only add to or remove from the visual tree depending on the changes in the `ListCollectionView`.

I hope this solution should boost my app's performance, since I rarely change the raw list, but I often alter filtering, sorting and grouping.

Do I need to create a custom control inheriting from `ListView` (or `GridView`) to do this, or is there another way?

Comment: It would have been better if you were attached some code,

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DeferRefresh, this delay automatic refresh until the defer cycle is existed. See if that helps.

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SomeListView.ItemsSource);
using (view.DeferRefresh())
{
  view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
  view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Country"));
  view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Active"));
}
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/08/28/collectionview-deferrefresh-my-new-best-friend.aspx

Comment: I have tested it and it did bring a minor speed up, but I still feel that this does not solve the core of the problem -- all of the visual elements for the items being recreated on refresh (even if only once).

Comment: As comment by Jacob, you'll really need to paste your code for further investigation. our hands are pretty tight here. At least a snapshot with profiler like DotTrace would expose the underneath problem a bit more.